# Javascript / Angular, how change column position of html table, when press button?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table, the user can modify the columns order pressing an left arrow button when the user press again the button, the column return to original position. (without any library, pure js, ts, angular)

I want to change the column position when user press a button

Answer (score 1):

its best to get the element ID and inject the class.
*** html ***

```
<a (click)="showHide()"></a>

<div id="yourid" class="hide"></div>
```

*** component ***

```
showHide = false;
showHide():void {
    const htmlEl = document.getElementById('yourid') as HTMLElement;
    showHide=!showHide;
    if(showHide){
      htmlEl.classList.remove('hide');
      htmlEl.classList.add('show');
    } else {
      htmlEl.classList.value="hide"
   }
}
```

*** css ***

```
.hide {
display: none !important;
height: 0 !important ;
visibility: hidden !important;
}
.show {
display: block !important;
height: 100% !important;
visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, at the end, I prefer to used div with flex or grid to made the table its more easy to make a responsive table

Comment: Jose - this was as an example - your question was, how do I programmatically get an id and add a class.